# Discord.js - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is in main.js:

```
const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');

const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = 'js!';

const fs = require('fs');

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if(err) console.error(error)
    let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
    if (jsfiles.length <= 0) {
      return console.log("No commands to log in FOLDER NAME")
    }
    console.log(`Loading ${jsfiles.length} commands from FOLDER NAME...`)
    jsfiles.forEach((f,i) => {
      let props = require(`./commands/${f}`)
      console.log(`${i + 1}: ${f} loaded!`)
      client.commands.set(f, props)
    })
  });

client.once('ready',() => {
    console.log('bot is on')
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        let cmd = client.commands.get(command+".js")
            if (cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args, prefix)
    } 
});

client.login('Prefix')
```

And this is in ping.js:

```
const { Client, Intents, DiscordAPIError } = require('discord.js');

const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args, prefix) => {
    var ping = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp + " ms";

    message.channel.send('Ma ping is' + ` ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}` + 'ms')
};
module.exports.help = {
  name: "ping",
  usage: "Ping Command",
};
```

But if I run main.js with the command `node .` in terminal, I get this error:

```
Loading 1 commands from FOLDER NAME...
1: ping.js loaded!
/home/ender/Desktop/Projects & Stuff/Coding/Discord Bot (JS)/main.js:23
      client.commands.set(f, props)
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
    at /home/ender/Desktop/Projects & Stuff/Coding/Discord Bot (JS)/main.js:23:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /home/ender/Desktop/Projects & Stuff/Coding/Discord Bot (JS)/main.js:20:13
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)
```

I use linux as my main os and the version of node.js I use is v16.11.1 and npm version is 8.0.0!

Please help, I started recently to use discord.js after I realized that discord.py was dead and I need help!

**Edit One**
This is how my files are organized: [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wuqf.png)

Comment: Can you edit your question to add an image of the folder where your bot commands are stocked so we can see if there's a file name/extention that causes problem?

Comment: You declared it as `client.command` (no s) at the top but you set it as `client.commands`

Comment: @MrMythical now I see that, and after I edited that now works! I tried to find what was wrong for like 2 days.. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

As @MrMythical pointed out, the only problem was that I forgot an "s" in the line `client.command = new Discord.Collection();`. After I put an "s" at the end, it works fine – no other error, so this is the answer to my own question!

Comment: If it was the problem, you can just click the "check" mark on a question to set it as THE answer

Comment: @MalikLahlou Unfortunately, though, there is no such "check mark" on *comments*. No answer other than this has (yet) been posted.

Comment: sorry I meant answer* ^^'

Comment: A user has to wait 2 days before they can accept their own answer.